# how to know that whether qmail is being used as spam sending trojan or proxy

Tags: spam, email

how to know that whether my qmail is being used as spam sending trojan or proxy

in CBL Lookup Utility i get following message:

> IP Address  is listed in
>   the CBL. It appears to be infected
>   with a spam sending trojan or proxy.
>
> It was last detected at 2010-11-23
>   11:00 GMT (+/- 30 minutes),
>   approximately 8 hours, 30 minutes ago.
>
> It has been relisted following a
>   previous removal at 2010-11-20 09:11
>   GMT (3 days, 9 hours, 58 minutes ago)

but i have already stopped sending newsletters from my site. stopped all kinds of mails. But i am getting blocked. So how to know that if somebody using my qmail? 
where can i find outgoing log of qmail in plesk instalation?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be due to Backscatter. The default Qmail install accepts emails for everybody and then bounces if the Email address is invalid. You can check if that is the case.

Normal Qmail log will be in /var/log/maillog. Not sure if Plesk changes it.